# Google Dataflow job writng to bigquery table with existing table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

i have a dataflow job which is writing to a bigquery dataset it is creating tis own tables .. can it write to a existing table with the exact same schema that is not partitioned .
I am using this inbuilt dataflow template Datastream to bigquery
I do not want to have any partitions on the new table that i created as dataflow creates the tables with the partition day. as bigquery has a limit of 4000